# ag-grid grouping group row display 0.0 for double type columns

Tags: double, ag-grid, group

I use AgGridReact's group feature. In the grid, I have double and bool type columns. After using group by, I noticed that there is "0.0" displayed at group row for double column, same for bool column, it display "X" for false value and check for true value which is expected to display for the column in each row. I don't see any value displayed at group row for string type columns. How can I not display anything for double and bool columns, just like string type columns?

I search through the ag-grid documentation on grouping, can't find any sample that has double or bool type columns. I searched internet, can't find any sample with either bool or double type columns.